# Web Blocks in Outsystems

Tags: outsystems

I have a screen and it contains 2 web blocks when I click a link in my web block A, I need to show the web block B on the screen. Can I possibly do that? How? I am new to Outsystems and stuck up on this. I am thinking is it possible? Thanks for any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose your webblock B in an IF binded to a Boolean variable let's say `Show`.

Then, right click on your webblock A, create a link to a new screen action. Then on your screen action change the value of the `Show` variable and use an `Ajax Refresh` to refresh your If created earlier. Don't forget to give a name to the IF so that you can refer in in the `Ajax Refresh` widget.